# A simple send and receive program in xcode

Tags: cocoa, xcode

Hiyee...doing any one knows where to find a simple send and receive program so that can communicate with each other in MAC...And it's in cocoa language

Comment: This question is too general. Send and receive what? Communicate with what? Are you looking for client-server or peer-to-peer communication? Also, "Mac" is not an acronym, don't capitalize it. Cocoa is not a language, it's a framework. The language you normally use is Objective-C.

Comment: a...a peer-to-peer communication...

Comment: anyway...erm...I'm not NSURL to do...

Comment: Almost the same as your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712508/client-to-client-messaging-in-cocoa and you'll get similar answers as well.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/PictureSharing/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Easy.  If you have XCode installed, go to /Developer/Examples/Networking on your mac and look at some of the xamples that use CFNetwork.